# Zend Forms (ZF1) How to add extra HTML after checkbox inside DD

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-form-collection

**UPD:** solved 
- added extra decorator.

I need to have the following result:

```
<dd id="daily_722-element">
    <input id="daily_722" type="checkbox" name="daily_722" value="1">
    <span> some text </span>
</dd>
```

I need to have **"some text"** wrapped by html tags just after checkbox, BUT before /DD (NOT after)!

My current code is as follows:

```
$chk = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('daily_shit');
$chk->setLabel('<span class="dt-note">'. $firstName. '</span>');
$chk->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);
```

**So it produces:**

```
<dd id="daily_722-element">
<input id="daily_722" type="checkbox" name="daily_722" value="1">
</dd>
```

And I cannot get a clue how to inject extra HTML after checkbox... but inside DD

Answer (score 2):

ZF1 decorators are a known source of confusion. If you put a little bit of effort though and get to know how they build up a resulting HTML it's quite simple to achieve what you want.

I suppose you haven't overridden ZF's default decorators for form element. Then they are (remember they're executed in order, altering what was returned by previous decorator):

- **ViewHelper** (renders input itself)
- **Errors** (appends error message, if needed)
- **Description** (appends element description, if set)
- **HtmlTag** (surrounds with dd)
- **Label** (prepends with label wrapped by dt)

Now what you need is adding `<span> some text </span>` after input (or errors/description), but before it's wrapped by `dd`. It means new decorator should be added to a chain of existing decorators in a correct position.

```
$chk = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('daily_shit');
$chk->setLabel('<span class="dt-note">firstName</span>');
$chk->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);

// Create a new decorator to render span you need
$postCheckboxDecorator = new Zend_Form_Decorator_Callback(
    array(
        'callback' => function () {
            return '<span>some text</span>';
        }
    )
);

// Add it into existing chain of decorators, right after ViewHelper
$decorators = $chk->getDecorators();
$decorators = array_slice($decorators, 0, 1, true) +
    array('PostCheckboxDecorator' => $postCheckboxDecorator) +
    array_slice($decorators, 1, count($decorators) - 1, true);

// Replace element's decorators with a modified chain
$chk->setDecorators($decorators);
```

Comment: Thanks, Max,
You set my knowlege up a bit :)
Anyway, at 4 AM Friday night everything seemed to be THE TROUBLE :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom decorator for this. Method `render` receives original content and changes it, than returns changed content.

```
class MyDecorator extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    public function render($content)
    {
        return $content . $this->_options['content'];
    }
}
```

And use it in form building

```
$form = new Zend_Form();

$chk = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('daily_shit');
$chk->setLabel('<span class="dt-note">maxa</span>');
$chk->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);

$decorators = $chk->getDecorators();
$chk->clearDecorators();
$chk->addDecorator($decorators['Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper']);
$chk->addDecorator(new MyDecorator(array('content' => '<span> some text </span>')));
$chk->addDecorator($decorators['Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors']);
$chk->addDecorator($decorators['Zend_Form_Decorator_Description']);
$chk->addDecorator($decorators['Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag']);
$chk->addDecorator($decorators['Zend_Form_Decorator_Label']);

$form->addElement($chk);
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked! Just wrapped up decorators.
    $chk->clearDecorators();
    foreach($decorators as $key => $decorator){
        $chk->addDecorator($decorators[$key]);
        if ($key === 'Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper'){
              $chk->addDecorator(new Decorator_Admin_HtmlTagSuffix(array('content' => ' <span>site: '.$some_meaningful_text.'</span>')));
         }
    }